# How would you measure automation or technological development?

Tags: technology, education-economics, technological-progress, automation

Hello dear Economists,

I am a Political Science Masters student and now I have this paper due 10 days. It is only a paper so I should not model something too complex and also I obviously lack the economics understanding for it.

What I am trying to do is, I want to see whether automation or technological development in general has an effect on governments education policy. This is the big question. Specifically I will use the Varieties of Capitalism approach and want to test the idea whether, lately, Coordinated Market Economies are also teaching more general skills rather than specific skills like Liberal Market Economies. In theory Coordinated Market Economies systems should differ in terms teaching, yet, It is now also often argued automation and technology has an impact on skillsets as well and people with specific skills are more in danger (I am not talking about STEM grads,engineers etc but more like machine operators) as they cant change industries that easy. Again, this paper is not going to be published anyware, it is very basic and I think the professor's expectation is whether we can construct solid arguments and integrate R and analysis to our paper.

What I am confused a little is how to measure the technological development/automation side of things. I did a little research myself and there are different approaches like using Total Factor Productivity or I also found robot density for manufacturing sector in 2020 but the data is very limited and also for skills side of the equation there is no data available for 2020. I am using post-secondary non tertiary education to capture the skills part (I am arguing this captures the vocational education so skills thought are specific, I am aware it is problematic as well.)

So I wanted to ask if do you have any reccomendations on how to measure the countries automation or tech development level, I would greatly appreciate any criticism or feedback.

Answer (score 1):

"What I am confused a little is how to measure the technological development/automation side of things."

There are several ways to do this in economics. TFP is not a good candidate because it is about neutral technology. Economists use capital equipment price or linear trend in a factor-augmenting technological change model. So if you are looking for cross-country variation, capital good price will be a good candidate. Robots adoption data can be another choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I looked for the capital equipment & good price but could not seem to find anything unfortunately and robots data is very limited as well :(